# React testing library - cannot access full child component in parent component test

Tags: react-testing-library

I am trying to write a test for a parent component which renders a child component. The child component is always rendered (not conditional), but `screen` from `@testing-library/react` doesn't seem to see the full child component.

When I do screen.debug(), I see:
`<div role="menu" />`

Even though in reality, the parent component looks like:

```
<div role="menu">
  <ChildComponent onClick />
</div>
```

The reason I'd like access to the child component is because the onClick of the `ChildComponent` isn't being called when I do `fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('menu'))` and I think it's because the onClick is not on that div, but actually a part of the `ChildComponent` ... the `onClick` changes what is rendered in the parent component and I would like to test that.

The `ChildComponent` looks like:

```
<div onClick>
  ....
</div>
```

I'm wondering why the full child component (and it's children) isn't rendered in `screen`? Is that to do with the library itself and is it not possible to go more than one level deep?

Comment: Please show the code of the `ChildComponent` component.

Comment: @LinDu I added the `ChildComponent`, but besides the onClick passed to it the rest is somewhat irrelevant (I think) ... I'm more curious why `screen.debug()` doesn't show everything that is rendered in the UI. It seems to only render elements 1 level deep.